# Is there some Boost functionality for simulating a Glib::Dispatcher?

Tags: c++, multithreading, glib, boost-signals, boost-signals2

I am currently in the process of refactoring an mid-sized software project. It contains a central kernel-like class that is used by multiple threads. Currently, this class uses a `Glib::Dispatcher` for handling signals that are emitted by multiple threads. Since one goal of the refactoring proccess is to get rid of `glibmm` entirely (since `Qt` shall be used as the new framework), I am trying to figure out a way of how to "simulate" the dispatcher functionality using `Boost`. I already looked into `Boost.Signals` and `Boost.Signals2`, but neither one of these libraries seems to offer an alternative to the dispatcher.

To clarify what the dispatcher shall do, here's a short description from [the official documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/classGlib_1_1Dispatcher.html):

> Glib::Dispatcher works similar to sigc::signal. But unlike
>   normal signals, the notification happens asynchronously through a
>   pipe. This is a simple and efficient way of communicating between
>   threads, and especially useful in a thread model with a single GUI
>   thread.
>
> No mutex locking is involved, apart from the operating system's
>   internal I/O locking. That implies some usage rules:
>
> - Only one thread may connect to the signal and receive notification, but multiple
>     senders are allowed even without locking.
> - The GLib main loop must run in the receiving thread (this will be the GUI thread usually).
> - The Dispatcher object must be instantiated by the receiver thread.
> - The Dispatcher object should be instantiated before creating any of the
>     sender threads, if you want to avoid extra locking.
> - The Dispatcher object must be deleted by the receiver thread.
> - All Dispatcher objects instantiated by the same receiver thread must use the same main
>     context.

Could you give me some pointers in the right direction? Is this the sort of functionality I can achieve using `Boost.Signals` or `Boost.Signals2`?

Edit: As a commenter rightly pointed out, using `Qt` would perhaps be an option. However, the class that I am refactoring is very low-level and I do not want to add this additional dependency.

Comment: Qt has a signals framework that does exactly what you want. Is there a reason not to use it?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, the class that is to be refactored is rather low-level and I do not want to include the dependency to an UI framework (which may easily change in the future, just as it is changing right now). I will mention this in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now opted for a total rewrite of the class in question. It turns out that I do **not** require the dispatcher functionality in the way it was provided by `Glib`. Instead, it was enough to use the normal `boost::signals2` signals, coupled with some signals from `Qt` for the *actual* graphical interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no simple way to do that, removing Glib in flavour of boost won't solve the problem which is more an architechtural issue than anything else. Replacing with Boost not gonna fix the design issue.
You should model your own signal interface, and try to adapt for each library, including Glib in the first place since it is already working, adding another indirection level to your problem will let you fix that issue.

Boost can help you if you look at [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/function.html). I dont consider replacing glib with boost to be a real step forward, boost is not a graphical library and it will be required at some point to add an interface with an implementation layer to your graphic engine.

Comment: Boost shall only replace some core functionality. As I wrote in my question, Qt will eventually handle the graphical stuff again. For the class I am describing, however, Glib is not the best choice any more.